# Is there a way to make the Div width be as wide as the content that is contained within it?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I've been trying to make a horizontal web page. However I don't want to keep setting the width to a certain width to accommodate the content that is floated is there a way to have the Div automatically re-size to the content that it contains? This way all the content is floated or "horizontally" scrolling? I'm using width:"specific size" but as soon as I have too much content it overflows is there a way to not have that happen and also where I don't have to specify a specific width size?

EDIT:
What I want is the whole website to be horizontally scrolling. I don't want just the specific div itself to have scrollbars, but I want the div to be able to adjust it's width to accommodate the content no matter if I have 3 divs within it or if I decide to add 6 divs later into the div.

[For example what I want is like this.](http://quiriniustheme.tumblr.com/) (Where even if I have more content it won't drop to the next line) I mean can this be achieved with css alone?) I specifically want that effect where the whole website is scrolling not just the div I don't know exactly if that website is doing that. Basically I want the whole website to scroll horizontally not just a scroll bar on the specific div itself.

For example vertically if you have more content you can keep scrolling down that is what I want, but I want that in a horizontal scroll of the website is that even possible?

Here is my code [Jfiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/QGzGG/) which is for tumblr but I want this for more than just tumblr. As I'm thinking of doing this for a regular website but where I manually will add more list items or Divs. I just want to see if there is a way to have the width adjust to the content so the floated content doesn't drop to the next line.

Comment: Show some code. What is in the div? Normal text doesn't overflow when you set the width to a specific value.

Comment: @Razor do you want that your content when it exceeds the div's width should be displayed with the help of a scroll bar

Comment: that would be overflow:auto correct? which gives a specific div a scrollbar. I want the whole website to scroll horizontally which works when my content is floated but then everytime I have to adjust the container to the amount of width it takes up. However, in a traditional vertical website the website itself just adjust to the extra content by allowing you to scroll down. I have edited my main post to hopefully clarify my points if not please tell me so I can show more examples if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R46gv/) , is that what you need

```
div{
    width:auto;
    overflow:auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
}​
```

Comment: I basically want the whole website to scroll horizontally. While I want the DIV to be able to fit all the content without me adjusting the width for that DIV. But I don't want a scrollbar just on the specific div to show all the content. I updated my main post hopefully that makes my idea much clearer. If not please tell me.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is `display: inline-block;`

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZDJbH/

Comment: good answer , actually we are assuming that he wants something like that , but the actual question is not quite undertsood well,dont you think so?

Answer (score 0):

Set the css width property to auto

```
#yourDiv {width : auto;}
```

Comment: I think he wants a horizontal scrolling also if the content overflows , if I didnt misunderstood the question.So we will have to use overflow property , is that right?

Comment: Exactly how would this help? `auto` is the default value.

Answer (score 0):

1.`display:inline-block`
2.`float:left` or `float:right` Because it will destroy line box.
3.`position:absolute；（and without top, left or position:absolute)`  May be need to know information to use it.